# Counting number of layers selected in ArcMap TOC using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects

Has anyone ever tried to get the number of layers that are selected in ArcMap?  If I have a map document that has six layers and three of them are selected in the TOC, how does one count them using ArcObjects?  I have looked for a while at IContentsView.SelectedItem.  Documentation says it can be an enumerator, but I am having a hard time finding out actually what it's type is.  In C#, if I do

```
string myType = IContentsView.SelectedItem.GetType().ToString();
```

myType is "System._ComObject".  Not very descriptive...  Trying

```
if(IContentsView.SelectedItem is IEnumLayer)
```

and similar checks has been unintuitive... I wasn't sure if multiple layers were selected that they would be stored in there but that was my first guess.

Comment: There's an example here http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.1/ComponentHelp/esriArcMapUI/IContentsView_SelectedItem_Example.htm it should be IEnumObject http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/ComponentHelp/esriGeoDatabase/IEnumObject.htm

Comment: Thanks, Michael.  I think I saw something similar to this but I will give it another look when I have my code in front of me.  I didn't remember seeing an IEnumObjects.  Hopefully it is still there at 10.0.

Comment: http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//00250000026v000000 AND http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/IEnumObject_Interface/00250000026v000000/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IContentsViewSelection should work for you.

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//000v00000064000000

This is VB, but you should get the idea...

`Dim pCVSel As IContentsViewSelection = My.ArcMap.Document.CurrentContentsView`

Then:
`pCVSel.SelectedItems.Count` will give you the count of selected items in the TOC.

Comment: Thanks, @Dan.  This is probably cleaner than what I ended up doing. I looked at [link](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//000v0000006s000000) and finally realized that SelectedItem is an ISet when it contains more than one object.  I did the QI on that rather than on IContentsView.  I will give you the answer though since you are correct.  Thanks for your input!